# How to fix incomplete cmake file?

Tags: c++, cmake, build

So I am getting errors in my code - currently install opencv for a quick test.
what are the minute issues that i need to fix?

````
>>
>>
CMake Error at C:/src/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:573 (_add_executable):
  The target name "test" is reserved when CTest testing is enabled.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! ```

**cmake file:**


``` cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(test VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
````

Comment: What are you linking OpenCV against?

Comment: Do not use `test` as the name of the project. Also, `target_link_libraries` expects **target** name as the first argument, so `test` is not suitable here too.